# lots of java.lang.NullPointerException exceptions on website

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, nullpointerexception, resultset

i have register a free JSP hosting and upload my files(project) on server.
**website is working on local server without any error or exception**
but when i upload files on server there are lots of `java.lang.NullPointerException` on different pages and when i refresh the page it shows different exception(sometimes). and sometimes it also shows me the web page without any exceptions.

i just notice the following:

- page shows exception when it takes more than 5 second to load
- pages shows exception in line in which `Resultset` is invloved 
  example:              
      ResultSet rs=someclass.somefunction(somestring);
- exception is not encounted same again.
- **let the exception page ideal for about 2 minute and just hit refresh its working fine**

is there any problem in server i'm using?
website link: http://free.hostingjava.it/-socialbook/

Username: demo

Password: demo

help...

Comment: It looks like you have not configured your database to this server, so It's not getting `ResultSet` from database, not you're getting `NPE`

Comment: @improver database is configured properly. as if you write the wrong password it shows you you entered the wrong username or password and if its correct then it take you to loginhome.jsp

Comment: dont tell me in your database connection url you have mentioned localhost

Comment: only this line is causing it , Getphotoes.getallpics(Getphotoes.java:9) , check it

Comment: i changed the connection url before uploading website according to server database address

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid the exception is not constant just refresh your exception page several time and come back here again

Comment: sounds like a DB issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a problem of Database connection.

```
int u_id=0;
try{
    String u_name=(String) session.getAttribute("myses");
    ResultSet rs=Usedata.connectuserinfo(u_name); 
    if(rs!=null){
            u_id=rs.getInt(1);
            f_name=rs.getString(2);
```

It looks like you are having problem either in Database connection or you are getting an attribute `"myses"` from session is having value null. That's why it is a null pointer Exception.

Comment: but it worked fine on local server....and i checked that the value of session variable is not null

Comment: have you taken care of darabase credentials?

Comment: i know nothing about database credentials??
what is that?

Comment: I mean to say, Database's **username, password**.

Comment: ya its problem with database connection. I just changed the database server and now its working fine....